# Google Cardboard SDK's sample app issues on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, google-cardboard, 360-virtual-reality

I'm implementing the new Google cardboard sdk's VR View to play 360 degree videos.

The [Sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java) provided runs fine on all devices except Samsung phones with Android 6.0.1.

To confirm, I tested the project on Nexus 5 running 6.0.1 and Galaxy S running on 5.1 and on both cases it worked fine. I was wondering if anyone else has had similar issues while implementing the SDK on Android 6.0.1.

Here's the log output while running on Galaxy S6, Android 6.0.1

```
    04-24 00:49:17.041 13737-13737/? E/Zygote: v2
    04-24 00:49:17.041 13737-13737/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10289
    04-24 00:49:17.041 13737-13737/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
    04-24 00:49:17.041 13737-13737/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-G920F_5.0.2 ver=22
    04-24 00:49:17.041 13737-13737/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0004
    04-24 00:49:17.041 13737-13737/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
    04-24 00:49:17.041 13737-13737/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget
    04-24 00:49:17.051 13737-13737/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    04-24 00:49:17.061 13737-13737/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
    04-24 00:49:17.061 13737-13737/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
    04-24 00:49:17.071 13737-13743/? E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
    04-24 00:49:17.071 13737-13743/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
    04-24 00:49:17.081 13737-13737/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget rsrc of package com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget
    04-24 00:49:17.081 13737-13737/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
    04-24 00:49:17.081 13737-13737/? D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
    04-24 00:49:17.081 13737-13737/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller
    04-24 00:49:17.081 13737-13737/? D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
    04-24 00:49:17.081 13737-13737/? D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget
    04-24 00:49:17.081 13737-13737/? I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget, Feature store :{}
    04-24 00:49:17.081 13737-13737/? I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
    04-24 00:49:17.091 13737-13737/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget rsrc of package com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget
    04-24 00:49:17.181 13737-13737/? I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init 1.5.6
    04-24 00:49:17.191 13737-13737/? D/OrientationEventListener: mAccStuckCheckModetrue
    04-24 00:49:17.191 13737-13737/? D/OrientationEventListener: mRate36
    04-24 00:49:17.201 13737-13737/? I/SimpleVrVideoActivity: Intent is not ACTION_VIEW. Using the default video.
    04-24 00:49:17.201 13737-13737/? D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
    04-24 00:49:17.211 13737-13761/? I/SphericalMetadataMP4: Located spherical metadata: <?xml version="1.0"?><rdf:SphericalVideo
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:GSpherical="http://ns.google.com/videos/1.0/spherical/"><GSpherical:Spherical>true</GSpherical:Spherical><GSpherical:Stitched>true</GSpherical:Stitched><GSpherical:StitchingSoftware>Spherical Metadata Tool</GSpherical:StitchingSoftware><GSpherical:ProjectionType>equirectangular</GSpherical:ProjectionType><GSpherical:StereoMode>top-bottom</GSpherical:StereoMode></rdf:SphericalVideo>
    04-24 00:49:17.211 13737-13737/? I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget.SimpleVrVideoActivity isFragment :false
    04-24 00:49:17.211 13737-13760/? I/VrWidgetRenderer: Native renderer has just been destroyed. Dropping request.
    04-24 00:49:17.211 13737-13737/? D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
    04-24 00:49:17.221 13737-13737/? D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{46206f7 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
    04-24 00:49:17.221 13737-13760/? I/VrWidgetRenderer: Native renderer has just been destroyed. Dropping request.
    04-24 00:49:17.221 13737-13763/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
    04-24 00:49:17.241 13737-13759/? W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
    04-24 00:49:17.241 13737-13759/? W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
    04-24 00:49:17.251 13737-13759/? W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
    04-24 00:49:17.251 13737-13759/? W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ima
    04-24 00:49:17.251 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
    04-24 00:49:17.251 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.251 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.251 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.251 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.251 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wvc1
    04-24 00:49:17.261 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
    04-24 00:49:17.261 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
    04-24 00:49:17.261 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wvc1
    04-24 00:49:17.261 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
    04-24 00:49:17.261 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv7
    04-24 00:49:17.261 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv8
    04-24 00:49:17.271 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp43
    04-24 00:49:17.271 13737-13759/? W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
    04-24 00:49:17.271 13737-13759/? W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
    04-24 00:49:17.271 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.271 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.271 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.271 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.271 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.271 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
    04-24 00:49:17.281 13737-13763/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
    04-24 00:49:17.281 13737-13759/? I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
    04-24 00:49:17.291 13737-13763/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xe0dc47c4
    04-24 00:49:17.291 13737-13763/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    04-24 00:49:17.291 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/sorenson
    04-24 00:49:17.301 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.301 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.301 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.301 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.301 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.301 13737-13759/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    04-24 00:49:17.301 13737-13763/? D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
    04-24 00:49:17.301 13737-13759/? I/ACodec:  [] Now uninitialized
    04-24 00:49:17.301 13737-13778/? I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
    04-24 00:49:17.301 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] Now Loaded
    04-24 00:49:17.311 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: >>>UHQA ACodec::configureCodec : 10027000, 15000000
    04-24 00:49:17.311 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c14c4
    04-24 00:49:17.311 13737-13760/? D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1360x1000]-format:1
    04-24 00:49:17.311 13737-13760/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
    04-24 00:49:17.311 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: >>> getPortFormat 16, OMX.SEC.aac.dec
    04-24 00:49:17.321 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] Now Loaded->Idle
    04-24 00:49:17.321 13737-13737/? W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
    04-24 00:49:17.321 13737-13763/? D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget
    04-24 00:49:17.321 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] Now Idle->Executing
    04-24 00:49:17.321 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] Now Executing
    04-24 00:49:17.331 13737-13781/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    04-24 00:49:17.331 13737-13781/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    04-24 00:49:17.341 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: >>> getPortFormat 16, OMX.SEC.aac.dec
    04-24 00:49:17.341 13737-13759/? I/ACodec:  [] Now uninitialized
    04-24 00:49:17.341 13737-13782/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    04-24 00:49:17.341 13737-13782/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    04-24 00:49:17.341 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1224
    04-24 00:49:17.351 13737-13801/? I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
    04-24 00:49:17.361 13737-13737/? I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget.SimpleVrVideoActivity
    04-24 00:49:17.361 13737-13737/? I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget.SimpleVrVideoActivity
    04-24 00:49:17.361 13737-13801/? I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Loaded
    04-24 00:49:17.361 13737-13737/? D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
    04-24 00:49:17.361 13737-13800/? I/MediaCodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] setting surface generation to 14066689
    04-24 00:49:17.361 13737-13801/? I/ACodec: can't find wfdsink-exynos-enable
    04-24 00:49:17.371 13737-13801/? I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Loaded->Idle
    04-24 00:49:17.371 13737-13801/? D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0xddf2b808 for 1920x1080, color 0x105, rotation 0, usage 0x2900
    04-24 00:49:17.371 13737-13801/? I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] configureOutputBuffersFromNativeWindow setBufferCount : 7, minUndequeuedBuffers : 5
    04-24 00:49:17.381 13737-13800/? I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] signalFlush
    04-24 00:49:17.381 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] signalFlush
    04-24 00:49:17.381 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] ExecutingState flushing now (codec owns 5/5 input, 0/9 output).
    04-24 00:49:17.381 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] Now Flushing
    04-24 00:49:17.381 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,0)
    04-24 00:49:17.381 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,1)
    04-24 00:49:17.381 13737-13778/? I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] Now Executing
    04-24 00:49:17.391 13737-13737/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@437b33f time:42123750
    04-24 00:49:17.391 13737-13801/? I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Idle->Executing
    04-24 00:49:17.391 13737-13801/? I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Executing
    04-24 00:49:17.401 13737-13801/? I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now handling output port settings change
    04-24 00:49:17.401 13737-13801/? W/AHierarchicalStateMachine: Warning message AMessage(what = 'omxI') = {
    int32_t type = 0
    int32_t event = 3
    int32_t data1 = 1
    int32_t data2 = 117440527
    } unhandled in root state.
    04-24 00:49:17.411 13737-13801/? D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0xddf2b808 for 1920x1088, color 0x105, rotation 0, usage 0x2900
    04-24 00:49:17.411 13737-13801/? I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] configureOutputBuffersFromNativeWindow setBufferCount : 15, minUndequeuedBuffers : 5
    04-24 00:49:17.421 13737-13801/? I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Executing
    04-24 00:49:17.451 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:17.451 13737-13760/? W/GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-1-13737-0] bindTextureImage: clearing GL error: 0x500
    04-24 00:49:17.461 13737-13737/? I/SimpleVrVideoActivity: Sucessfully loaded video 10027
    04-24 00:49:17.461 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:17.661 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:17.681 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:17.711 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:17.751 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:17.781 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:17.821 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:17.851 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:17.881 13737-13760/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:18.121 13737-13760/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:18.271 13737-13760/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xee8c1344
    04-24 00:49:18.711 13737-13737/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
    04-24 00:49:18.801 13737-13737/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.simplevideowidget D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```